# Can i porposely corrupt a file through Java programming ? Also is it possible to scramble a file contents ?

Tags: java, android, file, corrupt

I want to corrupt a file intentionally through java Programming. I have heard that you can read a file Bytes and append any random bytes to it but i yet don't know how to implement it practically. **Could you please provide a snippet of code**..

> is it possible to scramble the contents of a file so that the file can be still opened but the content inside is no more readable

Comment: If you append bytes then the contents is still the same. Well for the appended bytes. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Look up how to read & write files and give it a try?

Comment: @greenapps I am new to Java and i want to play around with files.

Comment: @JamesZ thanks for the suggestion I'll give it a try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `RandomAccessFile` scrambler would be this:

```
private static final String READ_WRITE = "rw";
private static final Random random = new Random();

public static void scramble(String filePath, int scrambledByteCount) throws IOException{
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, READ_WRITE);

    long fileLength = file.getLength();
    for(int count = 0; count < scrambledByteCount; count++) {
        long nextPosition = random.nextLong(fileLength-1);
        file.seek(nextPosition);

        int scrambleByte = random.nextInt(255) - 128;
        file.write(scrambleByte);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

`RandomAccessFile` is exactly what it sounds like, a file that can be read from and written to at any position. You can choose the position by calling `randomAccessFile.seek(long position)`.
`Random` is also what it sounds like, a factory for random numbers, bytes, etc.
So essentially
A) open the file for read/write at any position
B) get a random position, get a random byte, write the random byte to the random position
C) repeat B) for `scrambledByteCount` times

Comment: Thanks a lot dude..!! You are a true life saver..!!

Comment: No problem, mate!

Comment: Would you kindly check my answer as solution if it satisfies you, please?